# Wordpress: how to rename / rewrite taxonomy name

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have created following taxonomy in wordpress function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_book_tax' );

function create_book_tax() {
register_taxonomy(
    'site_players',//taxonomy name
    array( 'milan','manu),//CP name
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Players' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'players' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_admin_column'    => true,
    )
);


 }


 add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Now I need to rename it or better to rewrite it changing the name into **site_no_players**.
There is a way to do it in WP?

Comment: Do you mean *after* having added terms for that taxonomy?

Comment: After registering the taxonomy and added terms...slug......

Comment: I'd have thought you'd need to go into your database and update each term's taxonomy. There is undoubtedly something (a plugin perhaps) out there that does this for you.

Comment: Expanding on @George, [Here's a plugin that might do the trick](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-taxonomies/installation/) but I'm not 100% sure it updates the database.

Comment: I just go into the database and do an `UPDATE` query on anything that needs to be updated.